# Shell simulator with pipeline and I/O redirection on linux

Tags: c, linux, shell, redirect, pipeline

I am trying to write a shell simulator on Linux that can execute single-process command, two-process pipelines, and I/O redirection.
As I executed single process with the followings correctly, however, there are some problems with pipeline.

```
Copy_STDIO();                                       //Copy the stdio for the restoration.
Redirection();                                      //Determine whether should do Redirection.
Pipeline(); 
Restore_stdio();                                    //Restore the stdio.
```

Above is my functions in main. First I copy the STDIO for the restoration after I/O redirection. Then I dup my file descriptor to the STD_IN and STD_OUT. Then I execute Pipeline, and at last I restore my STD_IN and STD_OUT. Everything sounds perfect, but actually it is not. My redirection of OUTPUT was fail, which means that it didn't write anything to the destination file(i.e. if in the single situation : ls > 123, 123 doesn't show anything), when my program is still running. But when I terminated the program with exit(EXIT_SUCCESS), it appeared!!(If with ctrl+c, it failed either), I don't know why!

```
void Redirection()
{
    fd_out = open(filename[0],O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT,S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);    //O_WRONLY and O_CREAT must use at the same time.
    dup2(fd_out,STD_OUTPUT);
    close(fd_out);
}
void Copy_STDIO()
{
    STDIN_COPY = dup(STD_INPUT);                                //Copy for the stdin and stdout
    STDOUT_COPY = dup(STD_OUTPUT);  
}
void Pipeline()
{
if(pipeline)
{
    pipe(&fd[0]);
    childID=fork(); 

    if(childID==0)
    {

        if(fork()!=0)
        {
            close(fd[1]);
            dup2(fd[0],STD_INPUT);
            close(fd[0]);

            execvp(args2[0],args2);

        }
        else
        {
            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1],STD_OUTPUT);
            close(fd[1]);

            execvp(args[0],args);

        }

    }

    usleep(5000);                                               
}
}
void Restore_stdio()
{
    dup2(STDIN_COPY,STD_INPUT);                                 //Restore the output and input to the stdin and stdout.
    dup2(STDOUT_COPY,STD_OUTPUT);
    close(STDIN_COPY);
    close(STDOUT_COPY);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal verifiable example, aka a piece of code that can be compiled?

Comment: Files need to be closed before they can be seen and read.  exit(0) ; closes all open files.

Comment: @ArifBurhan where should I add exit(0); ? I closed my fd_out after I redirected it to STD_OUTPUT.

Comment: @RobertLee It works pretty fine for me with `ls 123 > 123`.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin yeah but my pipeline will be error. Try cat 123 | grep a > 456. And type cat 456. If this correct, it will shows the content of files. My point is that file 456 will just show the content util the program terminate, but not show during the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pushed two commits on your own repository, they contain the fixes you need

```
void Pipelining()
{
   int otherID  = 0;
   childID = 0;
   int childs = 0;
   int ret = 0;
    if(pipeline)
    {
    pipe(fd);
    childID=fork();

       if (childID < 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "error: 1 ... %s\n", strerror(errno));
           return;
       } else if (childID > 0) {
           ++childs;
           otherID = fork();
           if (otherID < 0) {
               fprintf(stderr, "error: 2 ... %s\n", strerror(errno));
               ret = waitpid(childID, NULL, 0);
               if (ret < 0) {
                   fprintf(stderr, "error: 3 ... %s\n", strerror(errno));
               }
               return;
           } else if (otherID > 0) {
               ++childs;
           } else {
            close(fd[0]);
            ret = dup2(fd[1],STD_OUTPUT);
               if (ret < 0) {
                   fprintf(stderr, "error: 4 ... %s\n", strerror(errno));
               }
            close(fd[1]);

            ret = execvp(args[0], args);
               if (ret < 0) {
                  fprintf(stderr, "error: 5 ... %s\n", strerror(errno));
               }
           }
       } else {
            close(fd[1]);
            ret = dup2(fd[0],STD_INPUT);
           if (ret < 0) {
               fprintf(stderr, "error: 6 ... %s\n", strerror(errno));
           }
            close(fd[0]);

            ret = execvp(args2[0],args2);
           if (ret < 0) {
               fprintf(stderr, "error: 7 ... %s\n", strerror(errno));
           }
       }
       /* now it is safe to close pipe */
       close(fd[0]);
       close(fd[1]);
       /* wait children */
       ret = waitpid(childID, NULL, 0);
       if (ret < 0) {
           if (errno != ECHILD)
               fprintf(stderr, "error: 8 ... %s\n", strerror(errno));
       }
       ret = waitpid(otherID, NULL, 0);
       if (ret < 0) {
           if (errno != ECHILD)
               fprintf(stderr, "error: 9 ... %s\n", strerror(errno));
       }
   }
}
```

I made the following changes:

1. now both children are created from the same top-parent
2. now the top-parent closes his copy of pipe file descriptors
3. now the top-parent correctly waits for its children
4. added much needed status checks

Comment: Thanks!! It's very helpful to me!!

Comment: I found my mistakes in my code. I put my pipe() in the wrong place. It should be called after the first fork(),before the second fork(), not before the first fork() hahaha! And I also figured out my waitpid() problem. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: You don't need to add exit, this is happening now, where you can only see output after the program ends; you need to make sure all files are explicity closed, before you can see or read them.